# Automatically enable USB tethering when android device is plugged using a udev rule

Tags: linux, bash, usb, udev

I can run the following command to enable USB tethering when my device is connected

```
adb shell service call connectivity 33 i32 1 s16 text
```

and to disable it

```
adb shell service call connectivity 33 i32 0 s16 text
```

I have tested both of these commands and they are working.

I want to execute the first command whenever my device is connected to my pc. I know it can be done using something called a udev rule but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

UDEV rules that run a specific script when a USB device is attached or removed can be achieved by defining the rules under /etc/udev/rules.d.

This article should be helpful to you:

https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-run-a-script-when-usb-devices-is-attached-or-removed-using-udev/